# How do I add borders to points in tm_dots using tmap (R)

Tags: r, tmap

I am creating a simple map using tmap and would like to adjust the border colours of the points in tm_dot()

```
library(tmap)

data(World, metro)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons() +
  
  tm_shape(metro) +
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = "pop2020", border.col = "blue") +
  
  tm_layout(title = "World Cities Map")
```

However the above code, whilst producing the desired output overall, does not include borders around the points.
[image]
What's going on? All of the documentation, help guides etc suggest that this should work. Am I missing something? I have tried setting the border.lwd and border.alpha arguments to nonzeros but I get the same output. Am I missing something very obvious, or has tmap functionality changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `shape = 21` (default is `shape = 19` for `tm_dots`):

```
library(tmap)

data(World, metro)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons() +
  
  tm_shape(metro) +
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = "pop2020", border.col = "blue", shape = 21) +
  
  tm_layout(title = "World Cities Map")
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I missed this because somehow I thought shape 21 was the default.